# Multivariable calculus. Change from 5 variables to 3 variables.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, determinant, jacobian

**Equal number of variables**

Change of variable from 2d cartesian to polar coordinate is easy because the number of variables remain the same.

$\iint_{R}f(x,y)dxdy=\iint_{S}f(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))\left|\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r,\theta)}\right| drd\theta$

**Unequal number of variables**

I try to evaluate an integral by a change of variable from the [absolute barycentric coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system) in a square pyramid to Cartesian coordinate has the following formula:

$\vec{x} = \sum_{i = 1}^{5} w_{i}\vec{v}_{i}$ where:

- The constraint is: $1 = \sum_{i=1}^{5} w_{i}$
- $w_{i} \ge 0$
- $\vec{x} = (x, y, z)$
- $\vec{w} = (w_{1}, w_{2}, w_{3}, w_{4}, w_{5})$
- $\vec{v}_{i}$ are the 5 vertices of the square pyramid.

The correspondence between 3D Cartesian coordinate and the absolute barycentric coordinate is not one-to-one. See [Servaes](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/30382/servaes)'s comments.

The Jacobian matrix $J$ is 3 $\times$ 5 if I omit the partial derivatives for the constraint.

I can't use the usual formula for change of variable because the Jacobian $J$ is rectangular and I can't get the determinant of $J$.

**Question**

In general, how to perform a change of variable with unequal number of variables for a multivariable integral?

Comment: Already you know that $w_5=1-\sum_{i=1}^4w_i$, so $w_5$ is not a variable. Also, there must be some constraints on $\vec{w}$ as otherwise there are (infinitely) many $\vec{w}$ representing each $\vec{x}$.

Comment: More constraints are required to make the representation in barycentric coordinates unique.

Comment: @R zu It explicitly says they are *not*, in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Generalized_barycentric_coordinates).

Comment: I do not see the relevance. You have $5$ points in $3$-space, in stead of the $4$ points needed to make the coordinates unique (with the constraint $\sum w_i=1$).

Comment: Ok let me make this very concrete; consider the square pyramid with vertices 
$$v_1=(0,0,0)\quad v_2=(2,0,0)\quad v_3=(0,2,0)\quad v_4=(2,2,0)\quad v_5=(1,1,1).$$
Then with $\vec{w}=\frac{1}{5}(1,1,1,1,1)$ and $\vec{u}=\frac{1}{5}(0,2,2,0,1)$ we have $\vec{v}\vec{u}=\vec{v}\vec{w}$.

Comment: You have misunderstood. I have just given you a counterexample.  The answer confirms that you have misunderstood. Please consider the possibility that your understanding is incorrect. Over and out.

Comment: Ok. I get it. you are right.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get why the sampling was non-uniform. Now I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Barycentric coordinates are only of use when dealing with simplices. There the number of variables is one greater than the dimension of the simplex, and the representation is unique. Concerning the Jacobian one may say the following:

Assume that we have the following situation: A simplex $S\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ has vertices ${\bf a}_i$ $(0\leq i\leq n)$. The points ${\bf x}\in S$ can then be written in the form
$${\bf x}=\sum_{i=0}^n\lambda_i{\bf a}_i,\qquad \lambda_i\geq 0,\quad\sum_{i=0}^n\lambda_i=1\ .\tag{1}$$The $\lambda_i$  are the *barycentric coordinates* of ${\bf x}$. The representation $(1)$ then allows of the parametric representation
$$\psi:\quad S_{\rm st}\to S, \qquad(\lambda_1,\ldots\lambda_n)\mapsto {\bf x}={\bf a}_0+\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i({\bf a}_i-{\bf a}_0)\ ,$$
where $S_{\rm st}:=\{(\lambda_1,\ldots\lambda_n)\,|\,\lambda_i\geq0, \ \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\leq1\}$ is *the standard simplex* in ${\mathbb R}^n$. If we now are given a function $f: S\to{\mathbb R}$ in terms of the barycentric coordinates $\lambda_i$ then we can write
$$\int_S f(\lambda_0,\ldots,\lambda_n)\>{\rm d}({\bf x})=J_\psi\int_{S_{\rm st}} f(\lambda_0,\ldots,\lambda_n){\rm d}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)\ .$$
Here the Jacobian $J_\psi=|{\rm det}(A)|$, where $A$ is the matrix with the differences ${\bf a}_i-{\bf a}_0$ in its columns. This is the same as the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by these vectors.

In order to integrate over a more complicated body $B$, as your pyramid, you have to present it in terms of inequalities describing the exact boundary of $B$. It is a hard mathematical problem to determine the exact bounding (hyper)planes of a $d$-dimensional body defined as convex hull of $n\geq d+1$ points in ${\mathbb R}^d$. Note that the so-called cross body with $2d$ vertices $\pm {\bf e}_i$ $(1\leq i\leq d)$ has $2^d$ facets. (In ${\mathbb R}^3$ this is the octahedron with $6$ vertices and $8$ faces).

Comment: I edited the question to add that $w_{i} \ge 0$. Thank you.

Comment: And, there is no way to fix the Jacobain method? I tried to think about flux or transformation of finite volumes. Can I use a stress tensor to deform a cube to a simplex etc. Well, I am lucky that I don't have to solve this immediately. This is just for fun for now.

Comment: @Christian Blatter the constraint of positivity is only required for *internal* barycentric coordinates, i.e. to represent points inside the convex hull of the points used. It seems you are assuming that the question concerns integration over the interior of the polytope?

Comment: A generalization of barycentric  for convex polytope: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0898122113004422